# How can I use a texture pack on a Minecraft Pocket Edition server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am on Pocket Edition and I can’t use a texture pack on a (MCPE) server. It keeps saying that I can’t activate it while in a world/realm/server. So how do I use and activate my texture pack? I can’t go to the server settings to click on texture packs because that button doesn’t exist. So I am hoping to find answers from some Minecraft Pocket Edition players.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings/global resources in start screen in game and select the resource pack you want then it will apply it and play on the server trust me I used a pack on a server called lbsg